# How to split $content to receive <h2> and <p> while creating a shortcode in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

After changing a theme, in many articles I have an old shortcode. It includes `<h2>` and `<p>`. I would like to create a new shortcode with the same name in order to restyle the old one. I need different classes for `<h2>` and `<p>`.

I have this function:

```
function factoid_function( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="vf-box vf-box--normal vf-box-theme--primary | factoid-box">' . '<p class="vf-box__text">' . $content . '</p>' . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('fact-box', 'factoid_function');
```

This is HTML output.

```
<div class="vf-box vf-box--normal vf-box-theme--primary | factoid-box">
<p class="vf-box__text"></p>
<h2>What is mesoscopic imaging?</h2>
<p>Mesoscopic imaging involves looking at details of biological systems in the context of an organ, body part, or organism. It’s an approach that recognises that a heart, an arm, or a fish is more than just a set of cells. In any tissue, organ, or body part, cells are packed tightly together or arranged in relation to each other.
</p>
</div>
```

Why $content is thrown outside of the paragraph with the class?

How can I split $content in order to assign `vf-box__text` for a paragraph and `vf-box__heading` for h2?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do_shortcode for the content. And use the editor to make your `<h2>` and `<p>`.  Put those between the `[fact-box]` and `[/fact-box]`

```php
function factoid_function( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $output = '<div class="vf-box vf-box--normal vf-box-theme--primary | factoid-box"><p class="vf-box__text">';
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);
    $output .='</p></div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('fact-box', 'factoid_function');
```